Upstairs washer suds coming out of basement sink
I have a wash room directly above the basement kitchen. The clothes washer is on the same drain line as the downstairs kitchen sink. Every now and again suds come up past the p-trap into the sink which, as far as I know, should not be happening. What should I do to try and combat this?
It's important to note that the ABS drain line at the top of the kitchen photo connects to an iron pipe that is cemented into the basement slab. That line then connects toward the center of the home. I assume it's at a 5% grade but I am not certain (built in '74). Maybe a good snaking will do the trick?



it's a "P" trap named for the shape it makes as a contrast to an "S" trap

Is the sink used regularly? Maybe the trap plug is getting low due to evaporation. What does the sink trap look like?

As a complete aside, this is one of the reasons a lot of apartment buildings do not allow dishwasher or washing machines.

Washing detergent is low foaming, so either you've got a bad blockage or you're using a lot of detergent for the foam to come up through the trap

Running the garbage disposal usually solves this problem for me, although I'm not sure why.

The most likely cause is a partial blockage in the main drain line downstream of the kitchen.  When the washing machine drains, it pumps a lot of wastewater quickly, which is overwhelming the main drain and backing out the first available upstream exit.
You can try snaking it blind, but a partial blockage is hard to find and clean with a snake because you don't have 100% certainty that you've removed or even found the blockage.  I know "call a pro" answers are generally frowned upon, but a plumber with an endoscope/snake would be able to find it quick.
Alternately, you can rent the endoscope/snake from a DIY store and go at it yourself.
Just be happy it isn't an upstairs toilet backing out a downstairs lav sink.  Been there done that!

So we finally solved this riddle. The water has a full story drop in the ABS to a sharp 90 degree corner. We decided that at the corner the pipe is full of water so the soap bubbles, now agitated, can only escape upward against the resistance of falling water until they hit a T at which point they again take the path of least resistance. The trick is when the bubbles get to the pea trap - once the pressure gets high enough it works its way around the inside of the trap, into the disposal, and eventually into the sink. What a journey!
